# How to load google recaptcha siteKey dynamically using some component variable..?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, recaptcha

`<re-captcha formControlName="recaptcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey="reCaptchakey"></re-captcha>`

in component HTML and,

`public reCaptchakey: string = <SITE_KEY>;`

in ts file, but this is not working, so how to load site key value using variable..??

Comment: elaborate on whats not working ? Are you not able to render it on UI ?

Comment: yes not be able render on UI if variable is used..!! It works fine if I provide siteKey directly instead of variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution, Just change `siteKey="reCaptchakey"` to `[siteKey]="reCaptchakey"` and It will work fine..!!

Comment: Great fix, saved me some time! Thank you!